# In pandas, how to pivot a dataframe on a categorical series with missing categories?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, categorical-data

I have a pandas dataframe with a categorical series that has missing categories.

In the example shown below, `group` has the categories `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`, but there are no cases of `"c"` in the dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
dfr = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": ["111", "222", "111", "333"], 
    "group": ["a", "a", "b", "b"], 
    "value": [1, 4, 9, 16]})
dfr["group"] = pd.Categorical(dfr["group"], categories=["a", "b", "c"])
dfr.pivot(index="id", columns="group")
```

The resulting pivoted dataframe has columns `a` and `b`. I expected a `c` column containing all missing value as well.

```
      value      
group     a     b
id               
111     1.0   9.0
222     4.0   NaN
333     NaN  16.0
```

How can I pivot a dataframe on a categorical series to include columns with all categories, regardless of whether they were present in the original dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`pd.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) has a `dropna` argument which dictates dropping or not value columns full of NaNs.

Try setting it to `False`:

```py
import pandas as pd
dfr = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": ["111", "222", "111", "333"], 
    "group": ["a", "a", "b", "b"], 
    "value": [1, 4, 9, 16]})
dfr["group"] = pd.Categorical(dfr["group"], categories=["a", "b", "c"])
pd.pivot_table(dfr, index="id", columns="group", dropna=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `reindex`. This will work even if your `value` column is not numerical (unlike `pivot_table`):

```
output = (dfr.pivot(index="id", columns="group")
             .reindex(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["value"],
                                                          dfr["group"].cat.categories]
                                                         )
                      )
             )

>>> output
    value          
        a     b   c
id                 
111   1.0   9.0 NaN
222   4.0   NaN NaN
333   NaN  16.0 NaN
```